# Using "core hours" to refer to times a bus station has a lot of traffic

Tags: meaning, adjectives

Can I use core hours in this context?

> In the core hours the stop (bus station) is served often than in the late hours as well as on the workdays often than on Saturday or Sunday.

Comment: Aren't those usually called "peak hours"?  Maybe not...

Comment: @VictorBazarov, *peak hours* seems good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the usage is ideal for your context. From [an answer on the original Stack Overflow site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306155/please-define-the-agile-concept-of-core-hours)...

> **Core hours** are the period(s) when all team members commit to working on the project (and not doing administrative stuff or other projects).

That's a typical definition - others may vary slightly. But the point is "core hours" is essentially a reference to *the working hours of employees* (when all of them should be at work, so they can reasonably expect to interact with any other worker).

In OP's context we're talking about those portions of the day when *demand for services* (from customers/the general public) is highest. They're usually call ***peak times*** (or ***peak periods***).

---

This part of the answer is essentially proofreading/writing advice, but I would rephrase to...

> *The stop (bus station) is served more often **at peak periods and on weekdays**  than **off-peak times and weekends***